# Ruby: Using the ||= operator should be able to be rewritten in 'if' statements, but it doesn't seem to work.

Tags: ruby, memoization

I believe this line says "If `school[grade]` is true, then shovel `name` into it. If it's false then give it a value of `[]` and then shovel `name` into it:

```
(@school[grade] || @school[grade] = []) << name
```

If so, then that should be the equivalent to the following lines:

```
if @school[grade] == true 
  @school[grade] << name
else 
  @school[grade] = []
  @school[grade] << name
end
```

But it doesn't seem to work out. I can't figure out what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby `nil` is false, non-`nil`'s (other than `false`) are true.  So this is a better translation:

```
if @school[grade]           # if @school[grade] isn't nil or false
  @school[grade] << name    # append name to it
else 
  @school[grade] = []       # otherwise give it an empty array
  @school[grade] << name    # and then append name to it
end
```

The `else` clause could be reduced to a single line: `@school[grade] = [name]`.

Answer (score 1):

`x == true` checks whether `x` is equal to `true`, not whether `x` is truthy (which is what an array would be). Use `if @school[grade]`.

```
irb(main):001:0> !!5
=> true
irb(main):002:0> 5 == true
=> false
```